# MinimumOSVersion '$($(DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME))' is not a valid version

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, notifications, xcode12

I am getting an issue on Xcode 12.1 when I have added NotificationServiceExtension in my project. Its gives error while building and archive. This digest on Local system and build cab be uploaded on iTunes. But on Appcenter it fails to archive.

> error: MinimumOSVersion '$($(DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME))' is not a valid version. (in target 'NotificationServiceExtension' from project 'XYZ')
> Command ProcessInfoPlistFile emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure